# Ask for explanation of one vim command

Tags: vim

```
let i=1 | g/aaa\zs/s//\=i/ | let i=i+1
```

The above command add counter number after matched pattern.  So the following text is changed.

```
aaab
aaab
aaab
```

to

```
aaa1b
aaa2b
aaa3b
```

'|' joints commands into one command. In my opinion, the commands are executed sequentially like firstly **let i=1**, then **g/aaa\zs/s//\=i/** , finally **let i=i+1** . From the result above,  **s//\=i/**and **let i=i+1** are executed by **g** command. Can anyone explain?
The following command does wrong work. But I don't know why.

```
let i=1 | g/aaa\zs/s//\=i | let i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `s//\=i/`, the replacement string is terminated and the `|` is treated as an argument by global.  However, when you remove the trailing `/`, the replacement string to `s` consumes the `| let i=i+1`.  From the help doc for `sub-replace-special`, you can find:  "When the substitute string starts with "\=" the remainder is interpreted as an expression."  So the expression `i | let i=i+1` is evaluated, but the increment is not available outside of that evaluation.

Comment: "So the expression i | let i=i+1 is evaluated" I think your idea can't answer my question. In my opinion, let i=i+1 is not executed at all.

Comment: @river Not sure of this, but: if an expression is expected after `\=`, are you sure that `| let i=i+1` *is* an expression? I could not find similar constructions in vim expression syntax help page.

Comment: g/aaa/s//bbb|echo "ccc"     I test this command, " echo "ccc" " will be inserted.

Comment: @river `echo "ccc"` is inserted indeed but as a string, not as the result of a command execution. Also, there's no more `\=` in that command, so no *expression* should be expected?

Comment: g/aaa/s//\=i|echo "ccc"   here ccc is also not printed.

Comment: I think this is a bug.  If you remove 'let i=1', you get the error message 'Invalid expression: i|let i=i+1'.  That error message does not appear when i is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand your first command as:

```
let i=1 | g/aaa\zs/ ( s//\=i/ | let i=i+1 )
```

(Parenthesis are only here for explaining, they'd cause syntax error if typed).
i.e. everything after the `g/<pattern/` is a single command given as an argument to the global `g` command.

So indeed: we start with `let i=1`, then for all lines matching pattern `aaa` we execute: `s//\=i/ | let i=i+1` (substitution, then incrementing `i`).

Your second command does not work because `s` does not function the same way as `g`, and it does need an ending `/` after the expression to substitute to pattern.

Comment: " it does need an ending / after the expression to substitute to pattern" . Maybe it is not the key issue.

Comment: @river Well, maybe it's not. But maybe you could better explicit your question in that case: clarifying what you know / suspect / wants to know exactly (in regards with William's answer/comments for instance) could help answering.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `|` separates two Ex commands, and they are then indeed executed sequentially. But some commands take a `|` as part of their arguments. `:global` is one of them (full list at `:help :bar`). So, the special application of commands over matching lines is applied with both the `:s` and the `:let` commands (the latter of which can be shortened as `:let i+=1` BTW).